# How to fix Postgresql-11 installation failed error in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-11

```
E: Unable to locate package postgres-11
user@ubuntu:~$ pg_ctl start -D /etc/postgres/11/main
The program 'pg_ctl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install postgres-xc
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install postgres-xc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgres-xc : Depends: postgres-xc-client but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I think it should be `postgresql-11`  apparently `postgres-11` tries to install Postgres-XC

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Please do not post textual information as screen shots.